# Angular6: Data is not passed to child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to display loading message when the page is loaded. I have created loader component as child component and value is passed from parent. But for some reason loader is not being loaded.

I have tried the following code.

I have created a component for loader as below:

**loader.ts**

```
@Input() showLoader: boolean = false;
```

**loader.html**

```
<div class="modal-backdrop in" [style.display]="showLoader ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

Now From the component I need to show this loader, I pass on value as below:

**html**

```
<app-loader [showLoader]="loaderOn"></app-loader>
```

**ts**

```
public loaderOn: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderOn = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared should work... perhaps there is something missing or an error somewhere in your code; To make the change more observable, i added a 2 second delay in ngOnInit();

relevant **app.component.ts**:

```
  loaderOn: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loaderOn = true;
    }, 2000)
  }
```

relevant **app.component.html**:

```
Value sent from the parent: <mark>{{loaderOn}}</mark>
<app-loader [showLoader]="loaderOn"></app-loader>
```

relevant **loader.component.html**:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader>',
  template: `
    <p>Value received in the child: <mark>{{showLoader}}</mark> </p>

    <div class="modal-backdrop in" [style.display]="showLoader ? 'block' : 'none'">
    ...this is the div which we wanted to style...
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`*{color:blue}`],
})
export class LoaderComponent {
  @Input() showLoader: boolean = false;

}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gzxdo)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an ngIf?

loader.html

```
<div class="modal-backdrop in">
```

and hide and show with

```
<app-loader *ngIf="loaderOn"></app-loader>
```